Plotly.NET exception accessing the internet
I am using Plotly.NET in C# and it is returning an error when it is running on my server, but not my local. The stack trace seems to indicate that it is trying to access the internet - specifically using PuppeteerSharp - when I call GenericChart.ToBase64JPGString.
Note that my local has access to the internet, but the server does not.
Is there something I have to configure on my server to make accessing the internet unneeded? And is there something that has to be deployed on the server so that it doesn't need to go to the internet (it looks like it's trying to download a headless browser).
For reference, this is my stack trace:
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
     at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)
     at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponseTaskAsync(WebRequest request)
     at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsAsync(WebRequest request, Stream writeStream, AsyncOperation asyncOp, Action`3 completionDelegate)
     at PuppeteerSharp.BrowserFetcher.DownloadAsync(String revision) in /home/runner/work/puppeteer-sharp/puppeteer-sharp/lib/PuppeteerSharp/BrowserFetcher.cs:line 264
     at PuppeteerSharp.BrowserFetcher.DownloadAsync() in /home/runner/work/puppeteer-sharp/puppeteer-sharp/lib/PuppeteerSharp/BrowserFetcher.cs:line 235
     at <StartupCode$Plotly-NET-ImageExport>.$PuppeteerSharpRenderer.clo@81-4.MoveNext()
     at <StartupCode$Plotly-NET-ImageExport>.$PuppeteerSharpRenderer.Plotly-NET-ImageExport-IGenericChartRenderer-RenderJPGAsync@117.MoveNext()
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
     at Plotly.NET.ImageExport.AsyncHelper.taskSync@76.Invoke(Task`1 t)
     at Plotly.NET.ImageExport.AsyncHelper.runSync[a,b](FSharpFunc`2 job, a input)
     at Plotly.NET.ImageExport.AsyncHelper.taskSync[a](Task`1 task)
     at Plotly.NET.ImageExport.ChartExtensions.ToBase64JPGString@56.Invoke(GenericChart gChart)
     at PlotGeneratorService.PlotGenerator.Generate(ReportPlot reportPlot) in E:\BuildAgent\_work\569\s\PlotGeneratorService\PlotGenerator.cs:line 62


Without knowing which API call you're using, it's hard to say, but I woujld take a look at the Plotly source code and see what's actually happening when you make the call

All ImageExport extensions use PuppeteerSharp and therefore need a chromium executable. Per default, the lib tries to download that executable, but you can also use a local executable to prevent that.
See also
https://github.com/plotly/Plotly.NET/issues/295
and
https://github.com/plotly/Plotly.NET/issues/436
The gist is that you can set the executable path via setting this global variable: Plotly.NET.ImageExport.PuppeteerSharpRendererOptions.localBrowserExecutablePath
